# WCF how to return string wrapped in cdata?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, cdata

I have a wcf service that returns a Type instance.  Say MyObject.  MyObject has a string property (say CDataString)that i want wcf to wrap in a cdata section (because I'm returning an html fragment in a string property).  How the heck do i annotate MyObject.CDataString so that when WCF puts it on the wire its wrapped in a cdata section?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Ok I think i have to chalk this up to me being confused.  SOAPUI was returning this as my elelment:
<MessageContent>&lt;p>Please indicate a general topic?: A New Symptom/Condition&lt;/p>&lt;p>IsHealthCon&lt;/p></MessageContent>

and i was expecting the '>'s to be escaped to &gt; when i saw it wasn't doing that i wanted to force this to come back in CDATA section, but looks like how its returning is valid.  Sorry I was just confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending XML in string CDataString property should not create any issue, WCF is able to handle it, did you try sending XML over WCF in string property?, if you are facing error could you please post here.

Comment: Yes, WCF should automatically HTML encode the strings that are in your CDataString. I've been trying to achieve this same thing and have found that even if you manually add a `MyData.CDataString = "<![CDATA[" + myString + "]]>";` it comes out as `&lt;![CDATA[]]&gt;`